# Where is the Android Studio button that that imitate system application level termination?

Tags: android

Quite sometimes back in Android Studio, there's a button that can kill the app imitating system killing the app (at the application level), as per the picture below

[image]

The way kill the application is described in the article.

My question is, where did this button goes in the latest Android Studio (Arctic Fox 2020.3.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the icon has changed. It is still in Logcat, but a different icon.  One won't see it unless we lengthen the height of the Logcat View.

[image]